# I am trying to build a layout, but no mater how much I've tried I am getting the same error on my browser :

Tags: laravel

View [layouts.app] not found. (View: C:\wamp64\www\Laravel\e-commerce1\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\Macros\livewire-view-component.blade.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO... Pls post the code you are working with. Without code it becomes difficult to suggest anything. Post the code of your blade view and livewire component

Comment: Is there a file at `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` in your app? https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components

Comment: i understood you, but i didn't know where to put it ,please more clarifiction

Comment: Livewire assumes you have a file there. The documentation gives a bare-bones example of what it should contain. "By default, Livewire will render the ShowPosts component into the {{ $slot }} of a blade layout component located at: resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php"